# SQL Query generated by Drupal Views 3

Tags: views

I have created a view in Drupal 7 using views 3 and it is throwing some sql error in preview and the error message is not complete showing here.
How can I check this sql complete error message?
Is there any option to see SQL generated by view so that I can test the same on mysql client?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Umar

Comment: I have explored views more to see the sql query from view settings. I can choose to display the query; it's a checkbox called "Show the SQL query" on the Views settings page (admin/structure/views/settings).

The SQL error problem is still there. I want to see the sql error messeage.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recent log messages should show the complete error (if you click on the message link).

You can find recent log messages at http://YOURSITE.com/admin/reports/dblog, or by clicking -> Administration -> Reports -> Recent log messages